# HighCharts: how to update bar color when updating the point value

Tags: highcharts

I use the "update" command to refresh the value of a point in my series:

```
mychart.series[0].data[i].update(sigvalue);
```

Now I would like to update the color of this column/point as well.
I tried

```
mychart.series[0].data[i].color = "#FF0000";
```

But that did not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color should be changed by attr() function.

http://jsbin.com/ubapaz/10/edit

```
    $('#test').click(function() {
chart.series[0].data[4].graphic.attr("fill","#ff0000");
    });
```

API [**`here`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element.attr%28%29) for your reference.